# Change db schema or query to return balance for a given period of time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have came up with the following schema:

```
  CREATE TABLE products
  (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    quantity INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    purchase_price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    sell_price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    provider VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

  # payment methods = {
  #   "0": "CASH",
  #   "1": "CREDIT CARD",
  #   ...
  # }
  CREATE TABLE orders
  (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    quantity INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    payment_method INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
  );

  # status = {
  #   "0": "PENDING"
  #   "1": "PAID"
  # }
  CREATE TABLE invoices
  (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    price INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    status INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

  # payment methods = {
  #   "0": 'CASH',
  #   "1": 'CREDIT CARD',
  #   ...
  # }
  CREATE TABLE bills
  (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    payment_method INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
```

And the following query to select a balance:

```
SELECT ((orders + invoices) - bills) as balance
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(p.sell_price * o.quantity) as orders
    FROM orders o
    JOIN products p
    ON o.product_id = p.id
) orders,
(
    SELECT SUM(price) as invoices
    FROM invoices
    WHERE status = 1
) invoices,
(
    SELECT SUM(price) as bills
    FROM bills
) bills;
```

Its working and returning the right balance, but I want to create a chart using Morris.js and I need to change it to return a daily or monthly balance at a given period of time and in this format:

Daily (2017-02-27 to 2017-03-01)

```
balance | created_at
--------------------------
600.00  | 2017-03-01
50.00   | 2017-02-28
450.00  | 2017-02-27
```

And monthly (2017-01 to 2017-03)

```
balance | created_at
--------------------------
200.00  | 2017-03
250.00  | 2017-02
350.00  | 2017-01
```

What I need to change in my schema or query to return results in this way?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2289a9/2

Any hints are welcomed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `created_at` date in the SELECT list and a GROUP BY clause in each query.

Ditch the old school comma operator for the join operation, and replace it with a LEFT JOIN.

To return dates for which there are no orders (or no payments, or no invoices) we need a separate row source that is guaranteed to return the date values. As an example, we could use an inline view:

```
SELECT d.created_dt
  FROM (  SELECT '2017-02-27' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS created_dt 
          UNION ALL SELECT '2017-02-28'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-01'
       ) d 
 ORDER BY d.created_dt
```

The inline view is just an option. If we had a `calendar` table that contains rows for the three dates we're interested in, we could make use of that instead. What's important is that we have a query that is guaranteed to return to us exactly three rows with the distinct created_at date values we want to return.

Once we have that, we can add a LEFT JOIN to get the value of "bills" for that date.

```
SELECT d.created_dt
     , b.bills
  FROM (  SELECT '2017-02-27' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS created_dt 
          UNION ALL SELECT '2017-02-28'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-01'
       ) d
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT DATE(bills.created_at) AS created_dt
              , SUM(bills.price)       AS bills
           FROM bills
          WHERE bills.created_at >= '2017-02-27'
            AND bills.created_at <  '2017-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          GROUP BY DATE(bills.created_at)
       ) b
    ON b.created_dt = d.created_dt
 ORDER BY d.created_dt
```

Extending that to add another LEFT JOIN, to get invoices

```
SELECT d.created_dt
     , i.invoices
     , b.bills
  FROM (  SELECT '2017-02-27' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS created_dt 
          UNION ALL SELECT '2017-02-28'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-01'
       ) d
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT DATE(bills.created_at) AS created_dt
              , SUM(bills.price)       AS  bills
           FROM bills
          WHERE bills.created_at >= '2017-02-27'
            AND bills.created_at <  '2017-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          GROUP BY DATE(bills.created_at)
       ) b
    ON b.created_dt = d.created_dt
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT DATE(invoices.created_at) AS created_dt
              , SUM(invoices.price)       AS invoices
           FROM invoices
          WHERE invoices.status = 1
            AND invoices.created_at >= '2017-02-27' 
            AND invoices.created_at <  '2017-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          GROUP BY DATE(invoices.created_at)
       ) i
    ON i.created_dt = d.created_dt
 ORDER BY d.created_dt
```

Similarly, we can a LEFT JOIN to another inline view that returns total `orders` grouped by DATE(created_at).

It's important that the inline views return distinct value of `created_dt`, a single row for each date value.

Note that for dev, test and debugging, we can independently execute just the inline view queries.

When a matching row is not returned from a LEFT JOIN, for example no matching row returned from `i` because there were no invoices on that date, the query is going to return a NULL for the expression `i.invoices`. To replace the NULL with a zero, we can use the `IFNULL` function, or the more ANSI standard `COALESCE` function.  For example:

```
SELECT d.created_dt
     , IFNULL(i.invoices,0) AS invoices
     , COALESCE(b.bills,0)  AS bills
  FROM ...
```

---

To get the results monthly, we'd need a calendar query that returns one row per month.  Let's assume we're going to return a DATE value which as the first day of the month. For example:

```
SELECT d.created_month
  FROM (  SELECT '2017-02-01' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS created_month
          UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-01'
       ) d 
 ORDER BY d.created_month
```

The inline view queries will need to `GROUP BY created_month`, so they return a single value for each month value.  My preference would be to use a `DATE_FORMAT` function to return the first day of the month, derived from `created_at`. But there are other ways to do it. The goal is return a single row for '2017-02-01' and a single row for '2017-03-01'.  Note that the date ranges on `created_at` extend from '2017-02-01' up to (but not including) '2017-04-01', so we get the total for the whole month.

```
           ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bills.created_at,'%Y-%m-01') AS created_month
                  , SUM(bills.price)                         AS  bills
               FROM bills
              WHERE bills.created_at >= '2017-02-01'
                AND bills.created_at <  '2017-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
              GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(bills.created_at,'%Y-%m-01')
           ) b
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you @spencer7593 for the extreme detailed answer! Just curious: this `calendar` table will hold only dates? If so, it would need to be populated with every future date by a scheduled procedure. This is a common practice?

Comment: I don't know if its common to have a calendar table or not. (With other databases, it's pretty easy to generate a list of dates, Oracle recursive CONNECT BY inline view, SQL Server recursive CTE, etc. No easy facility in MySQL, so we did a `CREATE TABLE cal (dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB`, and inserted a contiguous range of rows that satisfies our requirements. Jan 1, 2001 thru Dec 31, 2037.